# Process memory management queries

Tags: memory, memory-management, process, kernel

Here is a picture summarizing my understanding of process memory layout as organized by kernel. I would like to understand

1)When is Segmentation and Paging process takes place? During compilation or right after the program is executed

2)  At any given instance is it by any means possible to access the physical address of any given entity(variable, object)  in my process

I found little information in Understanding kernel book or may be the explanation is too far from my understanding I am not sure. may be someone can help me in this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Keen Learner, 1) Segmentation and Paging process takes place right after the program is been executed. Segmentation fault occurs only when some part of the code present in the program tries to access protected memory or memory which is not present in its process/virtual memory block. Paging process, since we cannot have all the process related pages at the same time in the main memory. Appropriate Page is only brought in or swapped out accordingly during execution of the process. 2) As far as I know there is no mechanism/means to access physical address of a variable because everything we play around with is an virtual address and converting it to physical address is the job of **MMU**. Hope I have cleared your doubts :-)

Comment: Gautham thanks for this clarificaton. So this leaves me with an assumption that Logical address would be generated by the compilers during compilation?